# Elements of $\langle S\rangle $ for $\emptyset \neq S\subseteq G.$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, combinatorial-group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and let $\emptyset \neq S\subseteq G.$ Prove that if $G$ is a multiplicative group, then
> $$\begin{align}\langle S\rangle &= \{a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} : s\geq 0, a_i \in S, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
> &=\{a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} : s\geq 0, a_i\neq a_{i+1} \in S, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}\},\end{align}
> $$
>
> or, if $G$ is an additive abelian group, that $$\langle S\rangle = \{k_1a_1+ k_2a_2 + \cdots + k_sa_s : s\geq 0, a_i \in S, a_i\neq a_j\text{ for $i\neq j$}, 0\neq k_i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
>
> where the empty product is the identity element and $\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ or equivalently the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$.

I know that if $G$ is a multiplicative group, and  $a\in G,$ then $\langle a\rangle = \{a^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$ The statement is an extension of this fact, and it seems the second equality is much easier to prove than the first. Also, if $G$ is an additive group, all that's changed is the operation, so it suffices to prove the first equality (i.e. that $$\langle S\rangle = \{a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} : s\geq 0, a_i \in S, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}).$$
We claim that $T := \{a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} : s\geq 0, a_i \in S, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Observe that it clearly contains $S$. Indeed, let $a \in S.$ Then $a = a^1 \in T.$ Also, $e = a^0\in T.$ For any $a, b \in T, ab^{-1}$ is clearly in $T$. Thus, by the Subgroup Test, $T\leq G$. Since $S\subseteq T, \langle S\rangle\subseteq T.$

To show that $T\subseteq \langle S\rangle,$ let $H\leq G, S\subseteq H.$ Let $a_1^{k_1}a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} \in T.$ By closure under the operation and inversion, $a_1^{k_1}a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_s^{k_s} \in H$. So $T\subseteq \langle S\rangle.$

> Is this correct?

Comment: Suppose you have a smaller subgroup $R$. Then there is some shortest word in $T$ that is not in $R$...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm not sure what user3482749 is hinting about, since the hint is already covered by your final argument. And whoever told you the abelian version was easier to prove is mistaken

Comment: No reason to assume $S$ not empty since this is true in this case too.